# specific select work only when i add db name

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express

All of the select statments are fine. Now I have this one:

```
SELECT 
   ORG.id, ORG.img, ORG.name, ORG.city, ORG.address, 
   ORG.zip, ORG.telephone, ORG.telephone2, 
   ORG.fax, ORG.email, ORG.vaname, ORG.vanumber, 
   ORG.yor_photo, ORG.commission, 
   Clients.id AS yor_id, Clients.prefix, 
   Clients.fname, Clients.lname, Clients.phone, 
   Clients.pelephone, Clients.email, Clients.pid, 
   ORG.adddate, ORG.note
FROM Org 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (select * from Clients where yor = 1) as Clients ON Clients.company = ORG.id 
WHERE ORG.id=" & ORGID
```

It is not working, I get error "invalid object name"

If I add the DBNAME.DBO in front of the table name it works

The problem is that i don't want to change that on every project

Why is it not working?

**UPDATE**

the problem is not with the db name, the problem is with the **AS yor_id** in the select statment.
if i remove it the record retrieved is not full with all the data but if i write it the data is full but yor_id is empty

**UPDATE**

NEVER MIND, my bad! id column was corupted

Comment: By the way, `LEFT OUTER JOIN (select * from Clients where yor = 1) as Clients ON Clients.company = ORG.id` is equivalent to `LEFT OUTER JOIN Clients ON Clients.company = ORG.id AND Clients.yor = 1`. (Just in case you weren't aware.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before that query you need to write

```
use DBNAME
```

in order to switch to your dbname.

Probably you are running that query on master database, so just do this and should work:

```
use DBNAME

SELECT 
   ORG.id, ORG.img, ORG.name, ORG.city, ORG.address, 
   ORG.zip, ORG.telephone, ORG.telephone2, 
   ORG.fax, ORG.email, ORG.vaname, ORG.vanumber, 
   ORG.yor_photo, ORG.commission, 
   Clients.id AS yor_id, Clients.prefix, 
   Clients.fname, Clients.lname, Clients.phone, 
   Clients.pelephone, Clients.email, Clients.pid, 
   ORG.adddate, ORG.note
FROM Org 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (select * from Clients where yor = 1) as Clients ON Clients.company = ORG.id 
WHERE ORG.id=" & ORGID
```

Comment: @Y.G.J: Most programming languages allow to select the database when or after you connect. How are you connecting to the database? Show us some code :)

Comment: @Y.G.J What Konerak said is correct. You need to check your DB connection and make sure you select your database, otherwise master DB will be used. What I wrote in my answer was how to do it in t-sql, but I guess you need to fix this on your db connection